# Knockout mobile js refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following code.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dan TV</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9, maximum-scale=12.0, minimum-scale=.25, user-scalable=yes" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    function currentProgram(context) {
      var title = '';
      $.getJSON(context.$data.uriCurrent, function(current) {
        if (current.series != null) {
          title = current.series.serieTitle
          if (current.series.episode.episodeTitle != null) {
            title = title + '<br>' + current.series.episode.seasonNumber + ':' + current.series.episode.episodeNumber + ' ' + current.series.episode.episodeTitle;
          }
        } else if (current.program != null) {
          title = current.program.title;
        } else if (current.film != null) {
          title = current.film.title;
        }
      })
      return title;
    }

    $(document).bind('mobileinit', function() {

      $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;

      $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;

      $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;

    });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-debug.js">
  </script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var viewModel = {
        channels: ko.observableArray()
      };


      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

      $.ajaxSetup({
        async: false
      });


      $.getJSON("http://beta.tvlive.io/channels/provider/FREEVIEW", function(data) {
        viewModel.channels(data);
      })
    });
    setInterval(function() {
      console.log("refresh program");
    }, 3000);
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="channelList" data-role=page>
    <ul id="channels" data-filter="true" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-bind="foreach: channels">

      <li>
        <img src="#" data-bind="attr: {src:image, alt: name}"> <font size="1" id="channelTitle" data-bind="text:name"></font>
        <h2 class="text" data-bind="html: currentProgram($context)"></h2>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/xbmc.launcher.js?v=2.1.0"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see the channels datafeed doesn't change but the program listing needs to be updated every minute. Ideally and in theory this should be quite simple. The setinterval funtion needs to be updated so that it runs the current program with context of each of the channels so that the current program gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure you code a little:

1) Add updateChannels method to your viewModel and call in the timeout function.

```
var viewModel = {
      channels: ko.observableArray(),
      updateChannels: function() {
        for (var i = 0, len = this.channels().length; i < len; i++) {
            this.channels()[i].update();
        };  
      }
  };

setInterval(function() {
   viewModel.updateChannels();
}, 3000);
```

2) create individual `channel` objects and add `update` method to each of them along with `title` property (at first json call):

```
  $.getJSON("http://beta.tvlive.io/channels/provider/FREEVIEW", function(data) {
      var channels = [],
          channelsFromJSON = JSON.parse(data),
          channelFromJSON,
          channel;
      for (var i = 0, len = channelsFromJSON.length; i < len; i++) {
            channelFromJSON = channelsFromJSON[i];
            channel = {
                uriCurrent: channelFromJSON.uriCurrent,
                title: ko.observable(),
                src: channelFromJSON.src,
                name: channelFromJSON.name
            }
            channel.update = function() {
                $.getJSON(channel.uriCurrent, function(channelData) {
                    var channelObject = JSON.parse(channelData), // I assume you get JSON from server 
                        title = 'no title';
                    if (channelObject.series != null) {
                        title = channelObject.series.serieTitle;
                        if (channelObject.series.episode.episodeTitle != null) {
                            title = title + '<br>' + channelObject.series.episode.seasonNumber + ':' + channelObject.series.episode.episodeNumber + ' ' + channelObject.series.episode.episodeTitle;
                        }
                    } else if (channelObject.program != null) {
                        title = channelObject.program.title;
                    } else if (channelObject.film != null) {
                        title = channelObject.film.title;
                    }
                    channel.title( title );
                })                       
            }
            channels.push( channel );
      };
      viewModel.channels(channels);
  })
```

3) And the html:

```
<ul id="channels" data-filter="true" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-bind="foreach: channels">
  <li>
    <img src="#" data-bind="attr: {src:image, alt: name}"> <font size="1" data-bind="text:name"></font>
    <h2 class="text" data-bind="html: title"></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @NikolayErmakov. The way it works at the moment is that each channel returns a different URL which points to the current program details (another json object). If i added this to the viewmodel how would it link to the specific channel. At the moment the currentProgram fires for each channel and correctly displays the program. But after 1 minute the current program may have changed. In your scenario how does the function get called for each channel again. The above code is all self-contained and the data is all available online. Perhaps you could amend and post.

Comment: I updated my answer though didn't test but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @NikolayErmakov. I did a few amendments and now have got it working. The channel.update method doesn't seem to have access to the channel object so I have had to pass that as reference. If there is a better way then let me know. Posting the complete code below if anyone is interested in a rough and ready tv program listing.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dan TV</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9, maximum-scale=12.0, minimum-scale=.25, user-scalable=yes" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <script>

    $(document).bind('mobileinit', function() {

      $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;

      $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;

      $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;

    });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-debug.js">
  </script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var viewModel = {
      channels: ko.observableArray(),
      updateChannels: function() {
        for (var i = 0, len = this.channels().length; i < len; i++) {
            this.channels()[i].update(this.channels()[i]);
         }; 
      }
     };

    setInterval(function() {
      viewModel.updateChannels();
      }, 30000);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $.getJSON("http://beta.tvlive.io/channels/provider/FREEVIEW", function(data) {
      var channels = [],
          channelsFromJSON = data,
          channelFromJSON,
          channel;
      for (var i = 0, len = channelsFromJSON.length; i < len; i++) {
            channelFromJSON = channelsFromJSON[i];
            channel = {
                uriCurrent: channelFromJSON.uriCurrent,
                title: ko.observable('fetching...'),
                image: channelFromJSON.image,
                name: channelFromJSON.name
            }

            channel.update = function(channel) {
                $.getJSON(channel.uriCurrent+'?'+Date.now(), function(channelData) {
                                    var channelObject = channelData,
                    title = 'no title';
                    if (channelObject.series != null) {
                        title = channelObject.series.serieTitle;
                        if (channelObject.series.episode.episodeTitle != null) {
                            title = title + '<br>' + channelObject.series.episode.seasonNumber + ':' + channelObject.series.episode.episodeNumber + ' ' + channelObject.series.episode.episodeTitle;
                        }
                    } else if (channelObject.program != null) {
                        title = channelObject.program.title;
                    } else if (channelObject.film != null) {
                        title = channelObject.film.title;
                    }
                    channel.title( title );
                })                      
            }
            channels.push( channel );
      };
      viewModel.channels(channels);
      viewModel.updateChannels();
    }) 
   });

  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="channelList" data-role=page>
    <ul id="channels" data-filter="true" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-bind="foreach: channels">

      <li>
        <img src="#" data-bind="attr: {src:image, alt: name}"> <font size="1" id="channelTitle" data-bind="text:name"></font>
        <h2 class="text" data-bind="html:title"></h2>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/xbmc.launcher.js?v=2.1.0"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for keeping me posted. However, if it was really only a few amendments to my answer I would appreciate your accepting my answer.